# MacVim with ZenCoding

Tags: macvim

I was trying to use [zencoding](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981) with MacVim with no luck. I followed the installation steps exactly, but when I run :scriptnames it doesn't show the autoload plugin part being loaded, and Ctrl-y doesn't expand any abbreviations. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

type CTRL-Y and `,` (comma). This do expand abbreviation works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Just out of curiosity, why do you type the leader `,` after `<C-y>` and not before? I guess they are both leaders...

Comment: @tmimicus yes, `,` after `<c-y>`. :)